# Roll-out of a python project

Tags: python, pyqt4, vtk

I'm looking for some information about the roll-out of a python project that uses several external libraries wrapped for python. Are there tools for this? What kind of external files do I need to use my project on anonther PC? Dlls? .pyd? What else? What to do with user- and pythonpath?

Background: I'm working on a C++ application with some other developers. To learn some python and because of some other reasons, I also build the functionality of this C++ app into a python app that does the same things the way I would like them to work. Several libs are used, QT (via PyQt4), VTK, and some more.

So what would I need to do to use my python program on another computer which the least amout of work for the other computers user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is highly dependent on what libraries you are using, how they are installed, which platforms you will deploy to etc.

Take a look at

- [Pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) (dependency handling, installation)
- [Virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) (python environment sandboxing)
- [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html) (automation)

Comment: The above combination makes for a great setup. Easy to push changes across multiple servers.

Comment: +1. What isn't explicitly stated is that you should use virtualenv on your server, as well as your dev machine.